# Using hero Image in about section by scrolling and resizing on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-resizing, responsiveness

I am building my portfolio website and I thought of using the hero section image into the next section of about us by moving and resizing the image, as a guess I have fixed about the height of 700px up to which image has to scroll. But the problem is that it is not working on resizing screen size. Is there a way to move it such that it always fits in about section on scrolling? Below is code snippets and gif showing the problem.

```
<!--HTMl-->
<section class="hero" id="hero">
    <div id="hero-img" class="hero-img" ><img  src="main.png"></div>   
</section>

/*CSS*/
.hero .hero-img{
    margin-left: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;  
}
.hero .hero-img img{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 160px;
    min-height: 320px;  
}

//JavaScript//
$(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
parallaxScroll();
});

function parallaxScroll(){
    var scr = $(window).scrollTop();
   var scrolled =document.getElementsByName('hero-img').length - $(window).scrollTop();  
   if(scr<690){
       $('.hero-img').css('top',(0-(scrolled*1.1))+'px');
       $('.hero-img').css('right',(0-(scrolled*.3))+'px');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.hero-img').css('top',('top'-(scrolled*1.1))+'px');
        $('.hero-img').css('right',('right'-(scrolled*.3))+'px');
    }
   
}
```

[Problem with resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QavO.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the code do:

Takes the position of the element with ID `id ="skills"` and subtracts from this value the height of the DIV element in which the picture is and sets this value as the maximum for scrolling.

You had set the `690` manually. The change is that now this IF listening automatically which will come first the `id ="skills"` or `690`

I hope I've been helpful

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function (e) {
    parallaxScroll();
});

function parallaxScroll() {
    var scr = $(window).scrollTop();
    var nel = $("#skills").offset().top - $("#hero-img").height();
    
    var scrolled = $('#hero-img').length - $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scr < nel && scr < 690) {
        $('.hero-img').css('top', (0 - (scrolled * 1.1)) + 'px');
        $('.hero-img').css('right', (0 - (scrolled * .3)) + 'px');
    }
    else {
        $('.hero-img').css('top', ('top' - (scrolled * 1.1)) + 'px');
        $('.hero-img').css('right', ('right' - (scrolled * .3)) + 'px');
    }

}
```

```css
.hero .hero-img {
    margin-left: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    /* bottom: 0; */
    top: 0px;
    max-height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.hero .hero-img img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 160px;
    min-height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="hero" id="hero">
    <div id="hero-img" class="hero-img">
        <img src="main.png">
    </div>
</section>

<div>
    ABOUT
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<div id="skills">
    SKILLS
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks  var nel = $("#skills").offset().top - $("#hero-img").height();  made it work.

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful :) Thank you that you mark this answer as accepted answer. You can add and positive rating on this post.